# Positive and negative voltage level shifter + inverter

Tags: inverter, cmos, level-shifting, negative-voltage

I am looking for a level shifter/inverter that not only changes the high-state to another voltage but also generates a negative low-state voltage. The output of *Inverter 1* is fixed to (0V … 600 mV), while the output of *Inverter 2* should be (1.2 V … -800 mV) respectively. I was able to achieve such a behavior with two cascaded CMOS inverters, but this is not ideal!

[image: cascaded CMOS inverters]

The reason why I am not satisfied is that there is a problem with the threshold voltages. For instance, I want V+ and V- to be modifiable (not fixed to -800 mV and 1.2 V). in some configurations this does not work at all because (V+-V-)/2 is not within the output range of *Inverter 1* and hence it is not within *Inverter2*'s threshold. Also, there are DC currents flowing because the output of *Inverter 1* is partially turning both transistors from *Inverter 2* on.

[image]

I know that there are CMOS level shifters which work for changing the high voltage level. But I also want to change the low voltage level, while keeping the complexity at a minimum. Can someone give me a hint in which direction to investigate? It is important to only use pure CMOS technology and no resistors for this design.

Comment: It appears like you are looking for someone to complete an entire design, it would be better if you could point it where you are stuck and what you have tried so far

Comment: Does it need to be CMOS - is it for a CMOS IC? And do you have access to lateral bipolar transistors in that process?

Comment: A quick google search suggests the standard approach is  cross-coupled level shifting cells. Have you tried that?

Comment: Is this a MOSIS process? As far as complexity goes: you're not designing from discrete components. Transistors are free, especially that there is always a limited number of level shifters even in large designs, since they only appear at interfaces.

Comment: How do you generate the +1.2V and -0.8V reference voltage? Can we assume that those are available? When doing logic level translation, the target output voltages must be available, so do you know how to generate them, or not quite?

Comment: @VoltageSpike isnt that exactly what I did. I wanted a hint in which directiion to research. Thanks to the community for the great answeres!

Comment: @Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica Yes it is inteded for IC design. and yes we can assume the voltage to be provided from annother module.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Thank you yes thats what I also tried out. However it didnt provide the felixility with the V+ and V- voltage levels while keeping the input Threshhold at  @ 0.3V

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Important Fudge Notice*: CircuitLab doesn't have any CMOS IC process devices, so I've fudged something that might represent a 0.5um process with +/-0.5V thresholds, at DC.

The drive strengths are a mere suggestion - they'd have to be optimized for a particular process.

### Assumptions

- The supply voltages are +/-1.8V.
- The input logic levels are 0V/1.8V.
- Output logic levels are -1.8V < VOL < 0 < VOH < +1.8V.

### Level Shifter 1

There are very many ways of designing such a circuit. The approach below translates the input to +/-1.8V logic level, and then uses that to drive the output buffer powered by the reference voltages.

It is an analog-style circuit with current sources and current mirrors, so that's definitely not a zero-current design expected in digital logic.

It may be a rather fast circuit, though. Reducing the static current consumption would require keepers at the output, and post-slew shutdown of the current sources.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fRhjOr.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

M1-M2 buffer the input. M3-M4 generate a current when the input is low. M5-M6 generate current when the input is high. The mirrors M9-M10 and M7-M8 copy/invert and combine those currents, which then drive the gate of the inverter M11-M12. M13-M14 drives the output.

### Level Shifter 2

This is a variant of the "classic" cross-coupled architecture.

VREF+ must be about 0.8V above 0V, and VREF- must be about 0.8V below 1.8V.

It has zero static current consumption.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f6N1nA.png)</sup>

1. When input is high, M3 and M11 turn on.

   - M3 turns on M10, discharging the the gate of M14, until both M14 and M22 stop conducting.
   - M11 turns on M13, driving output high.
2. When input is low, M5 and M9 turn on.

   - M5 turns on M12, discharging the gate of M13, until both M13 and M20 stop conducting.
   - M9 turns on M14, driving output low.

### Level Shifter 3

We can now combine ideas from the 1st and 2nd design: use the cross-coupled architecture to expand the control voltage range to the bottom rail, then use a reference-driven output stage as in idea #1.

This topology was described in [S. Kabirpour and M. Jalali, "A Low-Power and High-Speed Voltage Level Shifter Based on a Regulated Cross-Coupled Pull-Up Network," in IEEE Transactions on Circuits and Systems II: Express Briefs, vol. 66, no. 6, pp. 909-913, June 2019, doi: 10.1109/TCSII.2018.2872814](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8476228).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fGgkr6.png)</sup>

M4 and M10 are cross-conduction current limiters. The intermediate output stage M13-M14 is driven differentially from one of the current limiters. To change output polarity, M13-M14 would be driven from the source/drain of M4 instead of M10.

### Positive "Reference"

The reference scales the 1.8V rail down to 1.2V, using a voltage divider chain of triode-connected MOS devices. It then buffers that voltage using an op-amp with a common-emitter gain stage M206-M207 and an emitter follower output stage.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fuiJqY.png)</sup>

### Negative "Reference"

This is a circuit complementary to the one above.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fsr1Ve.png)</sup>

The “references” don’t provide a fixed voltage, only scale the supply rails, and have a good fraction of a mA of bias current total for the common-emitter stages. They are not very practical because of that.

A better op-amp architecture and an actual voltage reference would be needed to generate the rails in a practical way.